# Which containers on windows do not require a VM: windows or linux?

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DockerAndLinuxContainersOnWindowsWithOrWithoutHyperVVirtualMachines.aspx

says that Windows containers run inside a vm, while linux containers run on windows natively.

It looks like I am using Windows containers (as it gives me the option to change to linux containers)

[image]

However there is no virtual machine listed when I run Hyper-V manager as administrator.
[image]

When I run my docker containers, there is a virtual machine process:

[image]

So are my containers running inside a vm or natively?